# Counting number that falls in a bin based on coordinates

Tags: python

I was trying to count the number of molecules that falls into a particular bin based on the coordinate of the molecule. I think the nonzero option of numpy (similar to find() in MATLAB could do the job). At first, I did not use np.any but I got the error

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

When I used np.any, the error persist.

```
Lower limit = 0
bin_size=0.01
box=40
NO_bin= box/bin_size
for k in range(No_bins):
        if k==0:
            count = np.any(np.size(np.nonzero(data_matrix[:,3]>= k*bin_size+lower_limit and \
            data_matrix[:,3]<=(k+1)*bin_size+lower_limit)))
        else:
            count = np.any(np.size(np.nonzero(data_matrix[:,3]>=(k-1)*bin_size+lower_limit and \
            data_matrix[:,3]<=k*bin_size+lower_limit)))

            Atom_in_bin[j,2] = Atom_in_bin[j,2] + count
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you use a float value in your range, but this function takes only int arguments.
You can cast your No_bins into an int, but i advise you to build your bins with np.arange and then iterate on it :

```
bins = np.arange(0, box, bin_size)
for k, bin in enumerate(bins):
```

Your error comes from the and in the np.any.
The and operation is not define for arrays with more than one element.
Instead you have to use the np.logical_and function :

```
np.any(np.logical_and(data <= top_bin, data > bot_bin))
```

But if you are trying to build a histogram, numpy has a function for that : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html.

```
bins = np.arange(0, box + bin_size, bin_size)
hist, _ = np.histogram(data, bins=bins)
```